# How to hide button on create mode in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo

I know I can hide form button using built-in css class like `oe_edit_only` or `oe_read_only`

But how to hide an button when creating an item (and show the button only after the item is created, regardless when at read or edit mode)? I tried to look at the `base.css` file and found no class for this.

Is there a built-in css class for this? Or is there a function in the `QWEB` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating the method you don't have the id stored in the database yet. So you can do something like this:

```py
<field name="id" invisible="True"/>
<button attrs="{'invisible': [('id', '=', False)], }"/>
```